# How to format YAML data in Angular 14?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, yaml

I'm build an Angular 14 Application in which I have received YAML data in API Response. I need to show that on my frontend but  tag shows only plain text but not formatted and colorful with line numbers like other sites I'm referring to.
Is there any package I have to use or there is something else?

Thanks in advance. Looking forward to a helpful solution.

Environment Details:
**Node**: 18.16.0
**NPM**: 9.5.1
**Angular**: 14.2.11

Comment: I don't think there are any libraries that pretty-print YAML in Angular. You're gonna have to build your own ^^

Comment: I would take a look at highlight.js and see if there are any Angular wrappers or investigate how to incorporate highlight.js into an angular app.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to start with a code editor widget like [Monaco](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monaco-editor), the same frontend used by VSCode. That alone won't get you automatic formatting, but will do line number and syntax highlighting. You can look to [Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html) for the job of prettifying inputs.